# Self-referential Relationships in PHP Active Record

Tags: php, activerecord

I am trying to create a tree of pages using PHP Active Record and I seem to be having trouble getting it setup to work correctly.

Here is the code I am using for the Page class:

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord\Model {

    static $belongs_to = array(array('parent_page', 'class_name' => 'Page'));

    static $has_many = array(
        array('pages')
    );

    public static function get_top_level_pages() {
        return Page::all(array('conditions' => 'parent_page_id = 0'));
    }

}
```

My database table called Pages has the following columns inside:

```
id
parent_page_id
type
title
meta_title
content
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the "most correct" way to link a class to itself, but it seems to work for me.

First I changed the parent_page_id in the table to just be page_id and I made the class come together by using the following class:

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord\Model {

    static $has_many = array(
        array('pages')
    );

    static $belongs_to = array(array('page', 'class_name' => 'Page'));

    public static function get_top_level_pages() {
        return Page::all(array('conditions' => 'page_id = 0'));
    }

    public function get_parent() {
        return $this->page;
    }

    public function get_children() {
        return $this->pages;
    }

}
```

I created the get_parent() and get_children() functions because ->page and ->pages did not make sense to me and the functions help clear that up.

I am open to a better or "more correct" solution.

JP

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this (annoying issue).

You where missing the `foreign_key` (this will simply point to your column name).

I've modified your code and pasted it here below:

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord\Model {

    //make sure that you define the 'foreign_key'

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('parent_page', 'class_name' => 'Page', 'foreign_key' => 'parent_page_id')
    );

    static $has_many = array(
        array('pages')
    );

    public static function get_top_level_pages() {
        return Page::all(array('conditions' => 'parent_page_id = 0'));
    }    
}

$parent_page = Page::find(20)->parent_page; // this works fine
```